# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 7 - <div class='dInlineB' align="left">

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting error on line 7 syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

```
<div id='login_form_container'>
    <div class='dInlineB' align="left">
        <label class='login_form_label' for='email'>Email:</label>
        <input type='email' name='email' id='email' tabindex="1" class='login_form_input'<?=(isset($_POST['email']) ? " value='']."'" : "");?>
    </div>
        <div class='dInlineB' align="left">
        <label class='login_form_label' for='password'>Password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' tabindex="2" class='login_form_input' />
    </div>
    <div align="left">
        <div class='login_form_spacer'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class='dInline fs11'>
            <label for='login_form_stay'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='stayLogged' tabindex="3" checked='checked' value='1' id='login_form_stay' />

                Keep me logged in
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: `" value='']."'"` – `" value='']."` is a valid text literal, after that comes stuff that the interpreter can not understand because it violates PHP syntax. Please go learn the _basics_ of PHP string syntax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type='email' name='email' id='email' tabindex="1" class='login_form_input'<?=(isset($_POST['email']) ? " value='']."'" : "");?>
```

is malformed, please see the following correct line:

```
<input type='email' name='email' id='email' tabindex="1" class='login_form_input'<?=(isset($_POST['email']) ? " value='".$_POST['email']."'" : "");?>>
```

Code highlighting here on SO already shows where your error is at. What you missed was adding the value from `$_POST` to your input. In order to add PHP variable in a string you have to append the PHP like this: `"this is a string" . $variable . " continued string"` or with single quotes: `'this is a string' . $variable . ' continued string'`.

Using double or single quotes depends on whether you want to be able to use variables inline as well, which works on double, but not on single quotes: `"this $variable works inline" . 'but the $variable doesn\'t work here'`. For more info about the double/single quotes: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite line this like

```
  <input type='email' name='email' id='email' tabindex="1" class='login_form_input'<?=(isset($_POST['email']) ? " value='".$_POST['email']."'" : "");?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace :

```
<input type='email' name='email' id='email' tabindex="1" class='login_form_input'<?=(isset($_POST['email']) ? " value='']."'" : "");?>
```

with :

```
<input type='email' name='email' id='email' tabindex="1" class='login_form_input'value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line by

```
<input type='email' name='email' id='email' tabindex="1" class='login_form_input'<?=(isset($_POST['email']) /? " value='']."'" : "");?>
```